# Extract only month from string variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
['2019-02-18T00:00:00', '2019-03-28T00:00:00', '2019-02-01T00:00:00', '2019-08-01T00:00:00', '2019-02-20T00:00:00']
```

I want to extract only the month value in this list and put the result in another list to get this output :
`['02', '03', '02', '08', '02']`

Answer (score 7):

```
from datetime import datetime
data =['2019-02-18T00:00:00', '2019-03-28T00:00:00', '2019-02-01T00:00:00', '2019-08-01T00:00:00', '2019-02-20T00:00:00']

result = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').month for i in data]
```

Answer (score 3):

The month is always elements 5&6 of the string since the year is always elements 0-3 and a dash is element 4. Your original list is named “full_date_list” in my example.

```
month_list = [full_date[5:7] for full_date in full_date_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
import re
lst = ['2019-02-18T00:00:00', '2019-03-28T00:00:00', '2019-02-01T00:00:00', '2019-08-01T00:00:00', '2019-02-20T00:00:00']
r = r'\d{4}-(\d\d)-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'
x = [re.match(r, item).group(1) for item in lst]
print(x)
```